# Import of GeoServer WFS into uDig not working

Tags: geoserver, mac, udig

I'm trying to follow the example of how to integrate GeoServer with uDig that is on the uDig web page:

http://udig.refractions.net/files/docs/latest/user/getting_started/walkthrough2/WMSandWFSIntegration.html

I'm using a virgin install of both GeoServer 2.6.2 and uDig 1.5.0 RC1 on a Mac.

I don't seem to be able to add features using WFS from the GeoServer to uDig.

If I drag the WFS 1.0.0 link onto the map in uDig a 'processing drop event' popup is displayed temporarily, but nothing is added to the map. I can't see any errors in the GeoServer log, and I can't find a log in uDig - but no error messages are displayed.

I can confirm that the adding a WMS does work, which confirms that the GeoServer is working properly.

I've tried 'add data' in uDig - but when I select 'Web Feature Server' I get an error "An error occurred during page transition. This is most likely a programming error. Please report it". Is this related?

Can some one help shed some light on why the WMS isn't working?

It's possible that the documentation is out of date (it refers to an older version of geoserver), and it's also possible that the geoserver isn't configured out of the box the way that it was when the docs were written. I'm just learning these tools, and so I'm hoping that the answer is trivial.

Comment: I too am having a hard time getting uDig on OS X to talk to my geoserver over WFS.. But I'm new to this and I'm not sure my geoserver is configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tested with GeoServer 2.6 (http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/web/) on Windows with 1.5.0 RC1. Features are displayed correctly and both, drag&drop and Add Data workflow, were fine.

You could test against the demo server.

However, if any error occurs (programming error message), please report the issue and provide the logfile (http://udig.github.io/docs/user/reference/Help%20Menu.html) displayed in the dialog